# How to resize this highchart graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I use this [activity gauge highchart graph](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity/sand-signika). But, when I resize it. The layout become a mess. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/), I change the height and width of the graph. But, the label is misplaced.

```
 chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    marginTop: 50,
    width:700,
    height:700

},
```

Comment: I think you've to `redraw` chart with new attributes i.e. `height and width`. Try to set new attributes when required and redraw your chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to update `tooltip` and `stroke position` according to you new chart width and height like this :

```
tooltip: {
    ...
    positioner: function (labelWidth) {
        return {
            x: 350 - labelWidth / 2, // edited
            y: 320 // edited
        };
    }
 }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/504mmmhc/)